# Rails 4 on OSX: trouble with always having to reinstall rails on new terminal window/new session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

This has proven to be a pretty odd issue and I'm rather confused by it. I know there is plenty of documentation and SO q/a on this but I'm still pretty stuck.

I've been using this tutorial:

http://blog.nicoschuele.com/posts/install-rails-4-correctly-on-os-x-mountain-lion

which has actually been pretty helpful.

Maybe it's my `bashrc` file, but I'm really not sure.

The problem:

**I started a new rails project, all was going swimmingly. I cmd+t in the current terminal session to open a new tab. Do a `rails -v` and it's giving me the good ole 'sudo gem install rails` message.**

**Same thing happens if I close out of Terminal completely and reopen. the `ruby -v` has never seemed to be an issue: ruby is always there and rvm doesn't seem to be an issue.**

This is my `bashrc` file which I access by doing `vi ~/.bashrc`

```
  1 export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH
  2 export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
  3 export ANDROID_SDK=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/22.3
  4 
  5 PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/src/rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
  6 
  7 
  8 PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
  9 [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
 10 
 11 ### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
 12 export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
```

My `bash_profile` is the following:

```
  1 if [ -f ~/.bashrc ];
  2 then
  3     source ~/.bashrc
  4 fi
  5 
  6 source ~/.profile
  7 
  8 [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"     # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

If anyone could offer some insight as to why I need to keep installing rails, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: did you try restarting your computer?

Comment: Just did and same sudo gem install rails issue on `rails -v`. However, upon doing `rvm -v` I'm getting a Warning! PATH is not properly set up. Will look into this and report back here.

Comment: Ended up removing the source rvm stuff from bash_profile and put put it at the bottom of bashrc. Seems to be working (closing terminal/opening new terminal tabs).

Comment: ye, that can be a tricky one... it has to be on the end :) made the same mistake some months ago

Comment: @DnfD  glad you found a solution, do you mind posting it as an answer? In case someone else stumbles upon the same problem.

Comment: Yeah of course, not a problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems if you put the following line

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"     # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

**into `bash_profile` you can potentially run into issues.**

I ended up removing the above from `bash_profile` and putting it at the bottom of `bashrc`.

Yes, I had to install rails again (NOT using sudo, just `gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc`) for the app at hand but it seems this has solved the situation at hand:

I can close terminal, cd back into the rails app directory, do a `rails -v` and it returns `rails 4.0.2`

I can open new tabs in current terminal session, do a `rails -v` within the rails project directory and it returns `rails 4.0.2`